# ssh execute a shell script with arguments

Tags: shell, ssh

I am doing a ssh to a server and executing a shell script like below.

```
ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' user1@$some_ip_address  sh execute_all.sh '/usr/local/bin/ruby /home/user1/run.rb 2>&1 >> /home/user1/run.log'
```

Content of my shell file are as below

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "Please supply the command to be executed"
    exit 1
fi
echo "$1"
COMMAND=$1
eval $COMMAND
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi
```

When I run it all I get in logs is '/usr/local/bin/node'. I have also tried $* and it prints '/usr/local/bin/ruby /home/user1/run.rb 2'.
Obviously my eval command is not able to execute.

I want to run my whole command in shell script. How do I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting commands to run via SSH is tricky, try passing the entire command as a single argument, like so:

> ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' user1@$some_ip_address "sh execute_all.sh '/usr/local/bin/ruby /home/user1/run.rb 2>&1 >> /home/user1/run.log'"

Note the new double-quote characters.